# casting of objecttype

Tags: c#, types, casting

i've got a bunch of code doing something like

```
if  control == typeof( GridCurrencyTextBox ))
{
    ((GridCurrencyTextBox)(_control)).Text = ....
}
if  control == typeof( TextBox ))
{
    ((TextBox )(_control)).Text = ....
}
```

and so on.
i know i can estimate the type via control.GetType(), but the .Text property can only be set knowing the type at compiletime.

i'd like something like:

```
  Type t = _control.getType();
  (t(_control)).Text = .....
```

any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question what you're actually asking, but have you tried:

```
ITextControl textControl = _control as ITextControl;
if(textControl != null)
{
    textControl.Text = //...
}
```

Casting with `as` will give you the default value (`null` in this case) if the object you're trying to cast isn't the right type and, as far as I'm aware, most (all?) text controls in .NET derive from `ITextControl` (which just defines a `Text` property).

This assumes you're using ASP.NET. As mentioned by someone else, in Windows Forms `Control` has a `Text` property, so you would only need to make sure you casted to `Control`, and if it's already a control, the check is unnecessary  (except to make sure the value's not null).

If you're using any other type of Control and it doesn't derive from a common type that gives you a `Text` property, you might have to resort to using reflection, but this is far from ideal as it will be slow:

```
PropertyInfo text = _control.GetType().GetProperty("Text", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes, null);
if(text != null)
{
    text.SetValue(obj, /* some value */, null);
}
```

Comment: Isn't ITextControl a interface only available in ASP (since it is defined in the System.Web.UI namespace)?

Comment: thanks! exactly what i have looked for. i tried casting like newtype(oldtype) and that didn't work! i just had to change ITextControl to Control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.0 you can take advantage of the extension methods to rewrite your code too look a little bit better. Each of your comparison consist of few little steps:

1. Check for a specific type
2. If the object is of the specific type, cast it
3. Perform some action on it

Step 1 and 2 can be performed with the `as`-operator (your target must be a object then, as the `as` operator can only cast reference types). Step 3 can be done via a delegate. Thus a helper function could look like this:

> ```
> public static class Helper
> {
>     public static void Do<T>(object obj, Action<T> action)
>         where T : class
>     {
>         T castedObject = obj as T;
>         if (castedObject != null && action != null)
>             action(castedObject);
>     }
> }
> ```

Then you could call:

> ```
> Helper.Do<TextBox>(control, delegate(TextBox obj) { obj.Text = "your text goes here"; });
> ```

... for each type you have to handle. This solution uses a helper class and a anonymous delegate.

This is not the best solution. With extension methods and lambda expression you could have something like:

> ```
> public static class ObjectExtensions
> {
>     public static void Do<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
>     {
>         if (obj != null && action != null)
>             action(obj);
>     }
>
>     public static T Cast<T>(this object obj)
>         where T : class
>     {
>         return obj as T;
>     }
> }
> ```

... and use:

> ```
> control.Cast<TextBox>().Do(t => t.Text = "your text goes here");
> ```

for each type you have to handle. This line is even more readable than the previous solution. But in this case you have to know how extension methods and lambdas work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have property and you don't know the type you can always do this:

```
var type = _control.GetType();
var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Text");
if(propertyInfo!=null) propertyInfo.SetValue(_control,"Some Value");
```